# Extend XML file with missing elements using its XSD

Tags: xml

I have an XML file that does not match its XSD. The difference is that some elements are missing. From a XSD perspective these are not mandatory but still these need to be in. To make the file compliant I want to insert the missing elements (with no values). How can I do this in an automated way?

Thanks for the help!
Ron

Comment: The problem with this sort of request is that those optional elements often have optional content, the model may recurse infinitely deep, and in general there is no universal deterministic solution. It's generally better to make application-specific code responsible for handling and defaults... and/or to fix the code that erroneously believes "these need to be in." If they are optional in the schema, the XML file _should_ be completely valid without them; if that isn't working your code or your schema or your understanding thereof is broken.

Comment: Well, the appl producing the XML does not create the empty, mandatory elements. When I want to load the XML into another appl it checks the XSD and generates errors. The thing is that I cannot change the originating appl.

Comment: How can you define something that is not defined?   The only way is to get a list of missing tags and add them.  This may not be easy to automate because you may have the same tag repeated in different places in the code.  You can use XML linq to get a list of tags in XML using Desendants() then check to see which ones are not in the XSD Descendants.

Comment: If you just want to validate the document against the Schema and generate errors, any validating XML parser can do that for you, and wrapping an application around that would be fairly trivial. (Most parsers ship with samples you could use or adapt.) But that isn't what you initially requested; if you want the document populated with guidance from the schema, the key phrase to search for is "schema-directed XML editing or completion"